# Docker GitLab-CE: ulimit

Tags: docker, gitlab

on saturday I tried to install Gitlab-CE on a new root Ubuntu Server. I got this error:

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 24: ulimit: pending signals: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system
```

After setting the password and login (first time), gitlab shows me 404!

I already tried `docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions`, increase ulimit and so on!

```
sudo docker run -i \
--hostname ubuntu \
--publish 10443:443 --publish 10080:80 --publish 10022:22 \
--sysctl net.core.somaxconn=1024 \
--ulimit sigpending=62793 \
--ulimit nproc=131072 \
--ulimit nofile=60000 \
--ulimit core=0 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs/reconfigure:/var/log/gitlab/reconfigure \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

I definitely spent 15 hours on Google and tried out fixes. So far no chance

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and was able to get my local Docker gitlab-ce working by adding:

```
--privileged
```

See this issue:[3047](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/3047)